# RobotFramework - Run Tests on different environments

Tags: variables, appium, robotframework

I need to run specific tests for specific environments QA, Dev, Test etc., I have put a Tag on different tests i want to run on different, I am using AppiumLibrary as I am working on a mobile device, I was thinking to use a text file with all variables i need to execute for specific enviroments something like this.

```
    --variable Env:http://example.test.com:1111
    --variable remoteUrl:http://127.0.0.1:123/web/hub
    --variable platformVersion:8.0
    --variable platformName:Android
    --variable deviceName:Samsung
    --variable automationName:appium
    --variable appPackage:SamplePackage
    --variable appActivity:Activity
    --variable noReset:True
```

I need to pass this configuration in order for my app to hit the environment, Is there are way to use the `--variables` inside robot framework or is there a better approach to run tests on specific environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, all you need to do is pass that file as the value of the `--argumentfile` option. My team uses files that that. We have files named `smoke.args`, `prod.args`, etc. We use them like this:

```
robot --argumentfile dev.args tests
```

With that, any variables in the file are accessible in your tests just like any other variables.

Comment: so, once i pass the file on the command line, I can use them inside the variables in robot framework as normal variables ? e.g `${platformVersion}`?#