# Robot Framework - Running on diffrent devices file

Tags: robotframework, environment

This is a follow up on my previous question - [[RobotFramework - Run Tests on different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298417/robotframework-run-tests-on-different-environments/52300327#52300327])

I Have created a file for each of the environments, this is all working, right now I am just using My local tablet to test, I need to point to 10 different devices with different settings, Is there a way to store the configuration dynamically in the arguments file? Like get the configuration using robot store it in a variable and use that value in the arguments file?

Something like

```
//HERE sample code the get the androidVersion  =  ${Get_Android_Version}
```

.args file

```
--variable REMOTE_URL_ANDROID:http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
--variable PLATFORM_NAME_ANDROID:Android
--variable PLATFORM_VERSION_ANDROID:${Get_Android_Version}
--variable DEVICE_NAME_ANDROID:Samsung
--variable AUTOMATION_Name_ANDROID:appium
--variable PACKAGE_NAME_ANDROID:DiffrentPackage
--variable ACTIVITY_NAME_ANDROID:PackageName
```

> Ps. I know its not real robot code its just a sample of what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have any programming logic in an argument file. Instead of (or in addition to) using an argument file for this, you might want to consider a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files). Variable files are python code, so you can do any kind of logic you need in order to set your variables.

For example, you could pass the name of the environment from the command line, and use that in your test to import the variables for that environment.

### Example

test.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  ${ENVIRONMENT}_vars.py
...
```

smoke_vars.py:

```
def get_platform_version(platform):
    <your logic here>
    return $version

PLATFORM_NAME = "Android"
PLATFORM_VERSION = get_platform_version(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

command line:

```
robot --variable environment:smoke test.robot
```

You can also specify the variable file on the command line instead of in the test file. For example, you could remove the `Variables` setting and then do this on the command line:

```
robot --variablefile smoke_vars.py ...
```

All of this is very thoroughly documented in the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am a bit confused, `robot --variable environment:smoke test.robot` Could i specify diffrent env like so then `robot --variable environment:smoke --argumentfile QA1.args test.robot` ?

Comment: @Jhon: yes, of course. If you're using an argument file, you don't need to also include the `--variable` -- you can just do that inside the argument file. In other words, if you set it up right you only need `--variable` or `--argumentfile`, but not both.